# How to include interval of a certain data in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, intervals

```
x<-rnorm(100)
u<-runif(100)
t1<-(1/0.0105)*log(1-((0.0105/(exp(-8+0.03*x)))*(log(1-u))))
c<-rexp(100,1/1515)
delta<-1*(t1>c)
datinterval<-data.frame(t1[delta==1],c[delta==1],delta[delta==1])
datinterval$interval <- cut(datinterval$t1, breaks=seq(0, 500, 100))
```

This is the r code to obtain the interval for the data with delta=1. I want to insert it into data frame with complete data by using the the following code:

```
x<-rnorm(100)
u<-runif(100)
t1<-(1/0.0105)*log(1-((0.0105/(exp(-8+0.03*x)))*(log(1-u))))
c<-rexp(100,1/1515)
delta<-1*(t1>c)
delta
dat=data.frame(t1,c,delta)
dat$Interval[delta==1]<-cut(dat$t[delta==1], breaks=seq(0, 500, 100))
```

The code doesn't show the interval but only show 1,2,3,4...

[the interval part correctly shows the interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2sep.png)

[but the interval part shows only 1,2,3,4...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xhoi.png)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why that new interval variable only show 1,2,3,4 is that

```
class(cut(dat$t1[delta==1], breaks=seq(0, 500, 100)))
[1] "factor"
```

All you need to do is to change the last line of your code to

```
dat$Interval[delta==1] <- as.character(cut(dat$t1[delta==1], breaks=seq(0, 500, 100)))
```

I am not sure why the first piece of your code works. I will leave that to other member of the SO to answer. I am also curious to know.

PS: There is a typo at the end of the second piece of your code. It should be `dat$t1`, not `dat$t`.